# Why an Ideal beta spectrum is gaussian with Emax?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

[image]
[image]

Actual beta spectrum shows more intensity towards lower energy. This due to coulomb attraction between beta- and nucleus. But this deviation is from ideal behavior, which is Gaussian. But why the ideal distribution follows Gaussian?

Comment: Or why is there a minimum energy? Who says it is Gaussian? Why would it be symmetrical? Formulas do not look like that. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/fermi2.html

Comment: What is your source for "the ideal behavior is Gaussian"?

Comment: "It accounts for the nuclear coulomb interaction which shifts this distribution toward lower energies because of the coulomb attraction between the daughter nucleus and the emitted electron. " http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/beta2.html So my point is due to coulomb attraction distribution is shifted towards left. So non distorted one shall be symmetrical one. My Q is why the distribution is like this? I understand this continuous spectrum is due to E sharing between beta & anti neutrino. But why the distribution is like that with a max and 2 minima?

Comment: Details of the spectral shape in this document.  http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/ch374/ch418518/Chapter%208%20Beta%20Decay-rev.pdf

Comment: Is there any physical answer possible?

Answer (score 1):

The "ideal" spectrum is *not* a Gaussian. You can see find formula on p. 11 of the document you link to, from Oregon State; about halfway down the page. You can convert the formula to contain just the variable p (momentum) by writing the kinetic energy T<sub>e</sub> as a function of momentum. (Q is a constant, giving the total energy available in a specific decay.) Notice, as the text also says, that the function goes to zero both at p=0 and at T<sub>e</sub>=Q. A Gaussian does not become 0 except at +/- infinity. This function just (sort of) looks a little like a Gaussian.

This function is actually the simplest case, when the matrix element for the decay does not depend on p (or T<sub>e</sub>). Look at the formula a few lines above for how the matrix element enters the equation. Whether it is independent of p or has a more complex form depends on the spins and other details of the wavefunctions of the initial and final nuclei, but the function will always look similar to that shown on p. 29, with a maximum value somewhere in the middle and becoming zero at some maximum value of p (or T<sub>e</sub>).

This is further modified by the Coulomb interaction. The electron (for a β<sup>-</sup> decay) is attracted by the positively-charged nucleus and is slowed down: the whole spectrum is shifted to the left, toward smaller values. For β<sup>+</sup> decays, the positron is repelled by the nucleus and is accelerated: the spectrum is shifted to the right. On p. 30 you will find examples for both, for the rare case of <sup>64</sup>Cu which can undergo either β<sup>-</sup> and β<sup>+</sup> decay.

So, no Gaussians anywhere.